# Array for platform family vs rubocop

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rubocop

I am trying to use an array in Chef for platform_family, and according to the chef docs I have the right syntax, but rubocop is kicking my butt.

Chef docs: https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#value-for-platform-family

Any thoughts for a ruby newb?

```
 12 tcp_ports = value_for_platform_family(
 13   ['debian', 'rhel'] => [22, 443, 4172, 60443],
 14   'windows' => [443, 3389, 4172, 60443]
 15 )
```

And the rubocop error is

```
recipes/recipe.rb:13:3: C: Style/WordArray: Use %w or %W for an array of words.
  ['debian', 'rhel'] => [22, 443, 4172, 60443],
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea to name a hash key? `['debian', 'rhel'] => [22, 443, 4172, 60443]`, to work with it would be a bit "uncomfortable".

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That triggered "Style/PercentLiteralDelimiters: %w-literals should be delimited by ( and )." but that is easy to solve.. changed the brackets and everything is skookum.

Comment: what do you mean name a hash key? The left side is the platform family and the right side is the ports that need to be opened for each platform. I think it's good. I just reference "tcp_ports" wherever i need to and it picks up the correct ports depending what system it's running on.

Comment: Great, but is that a constraint of Chef?, because "any" character would work for a case like yours `['a', 'b', 'c'] == %w[a b c] && %w[a b c] && %w(a b c) && %w(a b c) == %w!a b c!`

Answer (score 2):

When working with collections Rubocop adds:

> Prefer %w to the literal array syntax when you need an array of words
>   (non-empty strings without spaces and special characters in them).
>   Apply this rule only to arrays with two or more elements.

```
# bad
STATES = ['draft', 'open', 'closed']

# good
STATES = %w[draft open closed]
```

Notice, this is bad from the view point in the Ruby Style Guide, but still working code.

So your example would be:

```
%w[debian rhel]
```

Comment: Thanks, if you switch the good example to have () instead of [] it works.

Comment: Can you clarify "this is bad from the view point in the Ruby Style Guide"?

Comment: Which part @muistooshort?, it's in the [repository](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#percent-w), same as added above.

Comment: So you're saying that `STATES = ['draft', 'open', 'closed']` is bad according to the style guide? It was unclear what "this" was referring to in "this is bad".

Comment: Maybe "_this __bad is__ from the view point in the Ruby Style Guide_" would be more clear?